# Laravel set id to the other table at the DB transaction

Tags: php, database, laravel

Here's my DB transaction...

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $superdoc = SuperDoc::create([
            'user_id' => $request->user_id,
            'project_name' => $request->project_name,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'end_date' => $request->end_date,
            'lines' => $request->lines,
            'words' => $request->words,
        ]);
        $lastInsertedId = DB::select('SELECT MAX(ID) FROM super_docs');
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    try {
        $document = Document::create([
            'superD_id' => $request->superD_id,
            'url' => $request->url,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'text' => $request->text,
            'doc_type' => $request->doc_type,
            'language' => $request->language,
            'date' => $request->date,
        ]);
        return response()->json($superdoc, 201);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    DB::commit();
}
```

I want to set the `super_doc` to auto-generated last id into the document table `superD_id` in the above transaction. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Knowledge about laravel bu i can give an idea, After inserting into **SuperDoc** table , you can get that model and the model will give you the model superD_id , that superD_id you can use in the Document Table.

So i think your code will look like this:

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $superdoc = SuperDoc::create([

            'user_id' => $request->user_id,
            'project_name' => $request->project_name,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'start_date' => $request->start_date,
            'end_date' => $request->end_date,
            'lines' => $request->lines,
            'words' => $request->words,

        ]);

        //$lastInsertedId=DB::select('SELECT MAX(ID) FROM super_docs');

    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    try {


        $document = Document::create([
            //$superdoc will have object of saved data which will also have SuperD_id
            'superD_id' => $superdoc->superD_id,
            'url' => $request->url,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'text' => $request->text,
            'doc_type' => $request->doc_type,
            'language' => $request->language,
            'date' => $request->date,

        ]);
       return response()->json($superdoc, 201);

    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    DB::commit();
}
```